# Where can I find the article of A. Borel: "Values of zeta-functions at integers, cohomology and polylogarithms"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Where on the internet can I find this article?

I know that it is in this book:  Current trends in mathematics and physics, Narosa, New Delhi, 1995.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting convenient access to a certain published document.

Comment: Google has scanned it: http://tinyurl.com/mrx65qs

Comment: @Carlo: Google only offers a free preview, not the entire article.  (Ownership of such an article is always a question for internet access, though bootleg copies may exist.)

Comment: @Mateo: For what it's worth, I'll add that this article by Borel is reproduced as item 157 in the final volume IV of his collected papers (which goes as far as 1999).  This was published by Springer.  If you can locate this source, it has the advantage of an added page of corrections and commentary by Borel.